# manual adjustement of newick tree and usage of ETE

Tags: python, tree, etetoolkit

I have a problem which seems to be too weird for me.

I have this newick tree:

```
(((637,5250,607,14782)6942,641)6441)0;
```

when i try to read it using ETE:

```
t=Tree("(((637,5250,607,14782)6942,641)6441)0;", format=8)
```

everything works normally, but now I want to make it bifurcating, so the new tree should be something like:

```
(((((637,5250),607),14782)6942,641)6441)0;
```

and now I try to read it using the same syntax as above:

```
t=Tree("(((((637,5250),607),14782)6942,641)6441)0;", format=8)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ete2-2.1rev539-py2.7.egg/ete2/coretype/tree.py", line 200, in __init__
    read_newick(newick, root_node = self, format=format)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ete2-2.1rev539-py2.7.egg/ete2/parser/newick.py", line 218, in read_newick
    return _read_newick_from_string(nw, root_node, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ete2-2.1rev539-py2.7.egg/ete2/parser/newick.py", line 280, in _read_newick_from_string
    _read_node_data(closing_internal, current_parent, "internal", format)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ete2-2.1rev539-py2.7.egg/ete2/parser/newick.py", line 351, in _read_node_data
    raise NewickError, "Unexpected leaf node format:\n\t"+ subnw[0:50]
ete2.parser.newick.NewickError: Unexpected leaf node format:
```

and this is driving me really crazy, anyone can help with this?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you have commas after ) and you shouldn't. Like ((637,5250),607) should be ((637,5250)607).

Comment: @petermlm if you do this, then `607` will be the parent node of `637` and `5250` and i don't want this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have format=8 in the Tree() function. According with [the specification](http://pythonhosted.org/ete2/tutorial/tutorial_trees.html#reading-and-writing-newick-trees) that means each node needs to have a name.

To work with format 8 you will need to give names to the nodes, like this:

```
t=Tree("(((((637,5250)a,607)b,14782)6942,641)6441)0;", format=9)
```

or

```
t=Tree("(((((637,5250)0,607)0,14782)6942,641)6441)0;", format=9)
```

You can also change to format 9:

```
t=Tree("(((((637,5250),607),14782)6942,641)6441)0;", format=9)
```

This changes the format to 9, which only requires the leafs to have names. You can also remove the format and just work with the first argument.